# Error deploying bar file using IBM Integration Toolkit

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I am working on a project with IBM Integration Toolkit 10.0.

I have some existing bar files which I am trying to deploy to remote IIB 10.0 node on linux machine using the IBM Integration Bus Toolkit.

The jar file `myaction.node.jar` has java class `FEBNode` in package as `com.abc.xyz.FEBNode`
The jar file resides in `/opt/abc/newplugin` directory and  this path is configured for "User lil path".

I am getting error like

```
BIP2241E: A Loadable Implementation Library (.lil, .jar, or .par) is not found for message flow node 
type 'ComAbcXyzFEBNode' in message flow 'Actions.JavaActions'. 
The integration node received an instruction to create a message flow node of type 'ComAbcXyzFEBNode', in message flow 'Actions.JavaActions'. 
The integration node cannot create nodes of this type because an implementation library for this node type does not exist in the LIL path.
```

The error is also seen while deploying from command line

```
./mqsideploy -i localhost -p 4414  -e default -a /tmp/barfiles/MyWrapper.bar.
```

Please give me some pointers on how to resolve this error.

Comment: I would recommend you to read about the shared-classes. This should fix your issue easily

Comment: Thanks for the reply. your suggestion on shared classes helped a lot!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you found the solution just based on a keyword. I've reposted my comment as an answer, feel free to validate it to help other people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to read about the shared-classes. This should fix your issue easily